# remove string before "="symbol in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I Have a CSV file output generated from some script as below:

```
name=1.1.1.1,managementaddress=1.1.2.1,,
name=1.2.2.1,managementaddress=1.1.2.1,activeaddress=1.1.2.1,activereadCommunity=public
name=1.1.2.9,managementaddress=1.1.2.9,activeaddress=1.1.2.9,activereadCommunity=public
name=1.1.2.16,managementaddress=1.1.2.16,,
name=1.1.2.2,managementaddress=1.1.2.2,,
```

from this output i want to remove the strings which are before "=" symbol. like the output should be:

```
1.1.1.1,1.1.2.1,,
1.2.2.1,1.1.2.1,1.1.2.1,public
1.1.2.9,1.1.2.9,1.1.2.9,public
1.1.2.16,1.1.2.16,,
1.1.2.2,1.1.2.2,,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed and a regex:

```
sed 's/[^=,]*=//g' file
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1,1.1.2.1,,
1.2.2.1,1.1.2.1,1.1.2.1,public
1.1.2.9,1.1.2.9,1.1.2.9,public
1.1.2.16,1.1.2.16,,
1.1.2.2,1.1.2.2,,
```

---

See `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: up voted this too, I was about to post an `awk` solution but the your regex works also in awk so meh :-)